# Bundle cohomology under a flop

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question is about the behaviour of line bundle cohomologies under flops. Specifically, my question is: *is the (dimension of the) zeroth cohomology of a line bundle preserved by a flop?*

This is motivated by the following example. For a toric variety, a flop corresponds to a change of the triangulation of the associated fan. But the zeroth cohomology of a line bundle is determined by the toric rays / weight system alone, i.e. it is unaffected by the triangulation. Hence it is unaffected by a flop.

Is the same true for more general varieties? Or is this specific to toric varieties?

A couple of notes:

- I have only been able to find statements about quantum cohomology being preserved, but this is too unfamiliar, so I do not understand the consequences.
- The zeroth line bundle cohomology is the same as the complete linear system of the associated divisor, and I am happy to discuss in either terminology.

Comment: Given the downvote: I'm happy to be informed if this is somehow a bad question, and I will delete it if so.

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with your question other than the fact that it is too high for me (yet)

Comment: This looks like a question that you've put some effort in to and could get a good answer. No need to worry about the downvote without explanation on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the smooth case this follows from Hartogs Theorem, which gives isomorphisms
$$
H^0(X,L) \cong H^0(X-Z,L) = H^0(X'-Z',L) \cong H^0(X',L),
$$
where $X$ and $X'$ are the varieties related by the flop, $Z \subset X$ and $Z' \subset X'$ are the flopping loci, and $L$ is the line bundle in question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Sasha. I do not immediately understand this, so I have two queries. (1) Is there a place to read the version of Hartog's Theorem you use here? And (2) have you made any assumptions about the line bundle $L$, for example that it does not intersect the flopping loci?

Comment: There is a proof of a version of Harttog's theorem necessary for this argument here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013385/sections-of-a-line-bundle-can-be-extended-if-the-complement-is-of-codimension-2