# Higher cohomology of line bundle and flops

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi: X \dashrightarrow X'$ be a flop between smooth projective varieties. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$ and $L'=\varphi_*(L)$ the corresponding line bundle on $X'$.

**Question:** What is the relationship between the cohomology groups $H^i(X,L)$ and $H^i(X',L')$?

For $i=0$ the two groups are isomorphic (see for example [Bundle cohomology under a flop](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540820/bundle-cohomology-under-a-flop)), but I am interested in the higher cohomology groups.

If it simplifies things, I am particularly interested in the case where the dimension is 3 and the flop is of "standard" type (flopping a copy of $\mathbf P^1$ with normal bundle $O(-1) \oplus O(-1)$).

Comment: This question is more suitable for Mathoverflow.